# Поиск самой длиной серии ничьих

Tags: алгоритм

Задача. Есть строка нулей и единиц разделенных пробелами. 0 выиграл первый игрок, 1 выиграл второй игрок. Задача найти в этой строке самую длинную последовательность, которая дает ничью (в которой фактически кол-во нулей и единиц будет одинаково). Как сделать обычным перебором за O(N2) вопросов нет. Как сделать за О(N)? Все мне говорят что задача похожа на классическую две суммы. Но у меня не получается. Понимаю что нужно использовать хеш, где хранить нужно сумму элементов как ключ, значение самый ранний индекс где они встретились. А дальше? Дальше нужно идти по исходному массиву и... и вот дальше у меня ничего не получается(

Comment: А требования к памяти, например, есть? Счетчик, равный 0. Идем слева направо, нуль - из счетчика вычитаем 1, единица - прибавляем. И запоминаем по ходу дела для разных значений счетчика левые места, где он такое значение получает в первый раз, и в последний. Все. Потом смотрим, для какого значения разность позиций будет наибольшей. O(N), но и памяти в плохом варианте тоже требует O(N).

Comment: Не сходится. Допустим последовательность 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0. Первый раз сумма ноль встретится на индексе 1 (считаем с 0). Последний раз встретится на индексе 7. То есть разница 6. А правильный ответ 8...

Comment: https://ibb.co/8bgmw5w Так понятнее?

Comment: Понятнее, да. Согласен. Но вот пример: 
0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1

Хеш начал получается {-1=0, 0=3, -2=1, 1=4} 
Хеш концов {-1=6, 0=7, 1=8}
Максимальная разница 6. А правильный ответ 8.

Comment: Все, сделал. Еще на проходе массива нужно проверять на индексе сумма 0 или нет, и если да, то если индекс больше чем уже посчитанное расстояние, то записывать его в ответ. Спасибо большое!